# Business Objects Infoview: How to Design Reports through Infoview? Suggestions?

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects, infoview

Very new to Business Objects, but I have a .NET background and PL/SQL background. I've been able to make the most basic reports, but I wanted to know if there were any good books or resources online that explain in detail how to design reports the way I'd like to such as grouping with sections, having two sections and segmenting only one of them, advanced functions like that.

Any suggestions or fingers toward the right places would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Greetings!
I assume you have BO XI (r2 or r3) installed.
Since you want to use Infoview i'll also assume you have a sample universe created, possibly star-schema like.

When you start Infoview new report (or Desktop Intelligence) there is an option to pick from one of the templates and from there you can immediatly change the layour of your report from simple-tabulate stype report to something more interesting, like cross-table.

http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/index.php its a great online resource for all your BO related doubts or needs =)

Fabio Prevedelli

Comment: I use BOB all the time, a great forum with lots of helpful resources and not too mention people.

Answer (score 0):

I havent come across too many books, but if you can convince your employer to send you on the introductory courses for DESKI or WEBI (depending upon your development environment of choice) then I can strongly recommend it.

The benifits of being able to quiz other participants on how they implement things in there environments or to ask further questions is a great resource and is well worth the coulpe $100.